# iis url rewrite with or without query

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have iis rewrite rule as follows.

```
<rule name="Redirect url1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^nsg/([!-~]+)" />     
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://test.com/gsl/{R:1}"
                appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Which is successful when I type in https://test.com/nsg/tasksearch.aspx, it will redirect to https://test.com/gsl/tasksearch.aspx. However, I also want it
when I just type in https://test.com/nsg, it can redirect to https://test.com/gsl. Can I do that?

Comment: Revise your regular expression in `match` tag, or add another rule for `nsg` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple change from your regular expression. Please try the below rules.

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="MyRule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^nsg([!-~]*)" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://test.com/gsl{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.